# Newb: best way to reference a calling class

Tags: python, pygame

Full game code here: http://pastebin.com/v9UvDYWy

I feel like I'm doing this wrong... I have a game class that has a loader method and then a player class. The player class needs to ask the game class's loader method for its image and also when it fires a bullet(using the bullet class) it again needs to ask for the bullets image... this is how I have that now...

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the player. """

    mouse = True

    def __init__(self, caller):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = caller.PLAYER_IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def update(self):
        """ Update the player location. """
        if self.mouse:
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()           # center player to mouse
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT-130                     # lock player to bottom of screen


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 0

    """ This Class Represents a Bullet"""
    def __init__(self, caller):

        #call the parent class constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = caller.BULLET_IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.speed = 8

    def update(self):
        """Move Bullet"""
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
```

Currently my game class has a method "Shoot" but I feel the player class should be the one to have this method... but if I do that then the references between Player class and Bullet class get messy. also the game should be the one that keeps the list of bullets etc so it can check for collisions but if the player is the one that initiates the bullet class then the player object needs a way of referencing the game object in order to create that list there.

here is the bullet collision logic:

```
for bullet in self.bullet_list:
    # check if the lasers(bullet) hit anything in the block list(enemies)
    bullet_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, self.block_list, True,collided=pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

    for block in bullet_hit_list:
        self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        self.score += block.scorevalue

    if bullet.rect.y < -10:  # remove bullet if it goes off screen
        self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        self.all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
```

I know my question wasn't super clear but I don't know how to really word it clearer... so I changed the code so the player has method shoot.. notice how the player now needs to temporarily hold the bullet image as the bullet class doesn't know how to find it otherwise.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the player. """

    mouse = True
    bullet_list = None

    def __init__(self, caller):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.image = caller.PLAYER_IMAGE
        self.BULLET_IMAGE = caller.BULLET_IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def shoot(self,caller):
        if len(self.bullet_list) < 3:
            bullet = Bullet(self)
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is(and centered)
            bullet.rect.center = self.rect.center
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            #pygame.Surface.fill(self.bullet.image,RED)
            caller.all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            self.bullet_list.add(bullet)
            #Play Bullet sound
            caller.sound_bullet_fire.play()

    def update(self):
        """ Update the player location. """
        if self.mouse:
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()           # center player to mouse
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT-130                     # lock player to bottom of screen


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    speed = 0

    """ This Class Represents a Bullet"""
    def __init__(self, caller):

        #call the parent class constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = caller.BULLET_IMAGE
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.speed = 8

    def update(self):
        """Move Bullet"""
        self.rect.y -= self.speed
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already passing `caller` into `Player.shoot`, why not just pass it into the initializer for `Bullet`?

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ...
    def shoot(self,caller):
        if len(self.bullet_list) < 3:
            bullet = Bullet(self, caller)
```

Comment: I feel like that isn't right... like it seems over complex to nest a Object ID like that. Im assuming there is a better way... hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pygame game that manages projectiles as well. It had a similar dilemma. What I found works best is to have the bullet class manage its own image, and the player to manage all of its subsidiary bullets, calling whatever functions contained within the bullets that the bullets need to update. The character also contains the function to project a bullet. All the game will manage is drawing the bullets (I have everything that gets routinely updated on the screen as a render updates group). This code is a bit general, but it works quite well for projectile management, and I have used this basic mainframe to quickly produce several games:

```
class Moveable(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,imageFileName):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.init2(pos,imageFileName)
    def init2(self,pos,imageFileName):
        self.right = pygame.image.load(imageFileName).convert_alpha()
        self.left = pygame.transform.flip(self.right,True,False)
        self.vertical = pygame.transform.rotate(self.right,90)
        self.image = self.right
        if self not in projectiles:
            self.direction = "right"
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
    def move(self,dx,dy):
        if self in special:
            pygame.display.update(special.draw(screen))
        #print COLOR
        screen.fill((COLOR),self.rect)
        #print COLOR
        if dx > 0:
            self.image = self.right
            if self not in projectiles:
                self.direction = "right"
        elif dx < 0:
            self.image = self.left
            if self not in projectiles:
                self.direction = "left"
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
        for other in collisions:
            if other != self:
                (awayDx,awayDy) = self.moveRelative(other,-1)
                if abs(dx + 1*(awayDx)) < abs(dx):
                    dx = 0
                if abs(dy + 1*(awayDy)) < abs(dy):
                    dy = 0
                dx = dx + 1*(awayDx)
                dy = dy + 1*(awayDy)
        for item in gravities:
            if item != self:
                (toDx,toDy) = self.moveRelative(item,1)
                dx = dx + (item.force*(toDx))/(self.rangeTo(item)/100)
                dy = dy + (item.force*(toDy))/(self.rangeTo(item)/100)
        self.rect.move_ip(dx,dy)
    def moveRelative(self,other,speed,exact=False):
        dx = other.rect.x - self.rect.x
        dy = other.rect.y - self.rect.y
        if exact == False:
            if abs(dx) > abs(dy):
                # other is farther away in x than in y
                if dx > 0:
                    return (+speed,0)
                else:
                    return (-speed,0)
            else:
                if dy > 0:
                    return (0,+speed)
                else:
                    return (0,-speed)
        else:
            angle = math.atan2(dx,dy)
            newx = speed*math.cos(angle)
            newy = speed*math.sin(angle)
            return (newy,newx)
    def movePerpendicular(self,other,speed):
        dx = other.rect.x - self.rect.x
        dy = other.rect.y - self.rect.y
        if abs(dx) > abs(dy):
            # this is to dodge a projectile
            if dy > 0:
                if dx > 0:
                    return (+speed/2,+speed)
                else:
                    return (-speed/2,+speed)
            else:
                if dx > 0:
                    return (+speed/2,-speed)
                else:
                    return (-speed/2,-speed)
        else:
            if dx > 0:
                if dy > 0:
                    return (+speed,+speed/2)
                else:
                    return (+speed,-speed/2)
            else:
                if dy > 0:
                    return (-speed,+speed/2)
                else:
                    return (-speed,-speed/2)
    def rangeTo(self,other):
        dx = other.rect.x - self.rect.x
        dy = other.rect.y - self.rect.y
        return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

class Stationary(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,imageFileName,collide,impermeable=False,alpha=False):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.init2(pos,imageFileName,collide,alpha)
        self.impermeable = impermeable
    def init2(self,pos,imageFileName,collide,alpha):
        drawn.add(self)
        updated.add(self)
        if collide:
            collidable.add(self)
        if alpha:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(imageFileName).convert_alpha()
        else:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(imageFileName).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = pos
    def rangeTo(self,other):
        dx = other.rect.x - self.rect.x
        dy = other.rect.y - self.rect.y
        return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

class unit(Moveable):
    def __init__(self,pos,image,health,projectile_count,fire_rate,team,speed,impermeable=False,special_reload={}):
        Moveable.__init__(self,pos,image)
        self.projectiles = []
        for number in range(projectile_count):
            self.projectiles.append(None)
        self.health = health
        self.team = team
        team.add(self)
        drawn.add(self)
        collidable.add(self)
        updated.add(self)
        self.firetime = fire_rate
        self.fire_rate = fire_rate
        self.reload = special_reload
        self.speed = speed
        self.impermeable = impermeable
    def maintain(self):
        self.firetime -= 1
        for item in self.reload:
            self.reload[item][0] -= 1
        index = 0
        for projectile in self.projectiles:
            if projectile != None:
                if projectile.update() == False:
                    projectile.end()
                    self.projectiles[index] = None
            index += 1
        collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, damagers, False)
        for other in collisions:
            if other != self and other.parent != self:
                try:
                    self.health -= other.damage
                except AttributeError:
                    print "Error: Unit Damage Collisions:", other.__name__, "lacks the attribute self.damage used to damage object"
                    raise RuntimeError
        if self.health <= 0:
            self.end()
    def project(self,bolt,speed=6,direction=None,target=None,accuracy=None,aimed=False):
        if bolt not in self.reload.keys():
            if self.firetime > 0:
                pass
            else:
                if direction == None:
                    if aimed == True:
                        direction = self.moveRelative(target,speed,exact=True)
                    else:
                        direction = self.moveRelative(target,speed)
                index = 0
                for projectile in self.projectiles:
                    if projectile == None:
                        self.projectiles[index] = bolt(self.rect.center,direction,self)
                        projectiles.add(self.projectiles[index])
                        updated.add(self.projectiles[index])
                        break
                    index += 1
                self.firetime = self.fire_rate
        else:
            if self.reload[bolt][0] > 0:
                pass
            else:
                if direction == None:
                    direction = self.moveRelative(target,speed)
                index = 0
                for projectile in self.projectiles:
                    if projectile == None:
                        self.projectiles[index] = bolt(self.rect.center,direction,self)
                        projectiles.add(self.projectiles[index])
                        updated.add(self.projectiles[index])
                        break
                    index += 1
                self.reload[bolt][0] = self.reload[bolt][1]
    def end(self):
        for projectile in self.projectiles:
            if projectile != None:
                projectile.end()
        drawn.remove(self)
        collidable.remove(self)
        updated.remove(self)
        special.remove(self)
        damagers.remove(self)
        explosion_triggers.remove(self)
        self.team.remove(self)
        screen.fill(COLOR,self.rect)
    def goup(self):
        self.directions = (0,-1)
        self.inertia()
    def godown(self):
        self.directions = (0,1)
        self.inertia()
    def goleft(self):
        self.directions = (-1,0)
        self.inertia()
    def goright(self):
        self.directions = (1,0)
        self.inertia()
    def magnitude(self,factor):
        return (self.directions[0]*factor,self.directions[1]*factor)
    def inertia(self):
        self.move(*self.magnitude(self.speed))
    def shoot(self,bolt):
        self.project(bolt,direction=self.magnitude(10))
    def aimshoot(self,bolt,vector):
        self.project(bolt,direction=vector)

class projectile(Moveable):
    def __init__(self,pos,direction,image,destructcount,damager=False,boomtrigger=False,simple=True,parent=None,arc=False,explodable=False,countdown=None):
        Moveable.__init__(self,pos,image)
        self.arc=arc
        self.destructCountDown = destructcount
        self.full = destructcount
        if self.arc == True:
            magnitude = math.sqrt(direction[0]*direction[0]+direction[1]*direction[1])
            if explodable == True:
                time = float(self.full)-float(countdown)/2.0
            else:
                time = float(self.full)/2.0
            self.change = float(magnitude)/float(time)
        self.parent = parent
        drawn.add(self)
        if boomtrigger != False:
            explosion_triggers.add(self)
        if damager != False:
            self.damage = damager
            damagers.add(self)
        self.directions = list(direction)
        self.explodable = explodable
        self.delay = 0
        if simple == True:
            if abs(self.directions[1]) > abs(self.directions[0]):
                self.image = self.vertical
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = pos
        else:
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.vertical,math.degrees(math.atan2(direction[0],direction[1])))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = pos
    def update(self):
        if self.delay > 0:
            self.delay -= 1
        else:
            screen.fill((COLOR),self.rect)
            collisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, collidable, False)
            for other in collisions:
                if other != self:
                    if other.impermeable == True:
                        self.end()
                        return False
            self.destructCountDown = self.destructCountDown - 1
            if self.explodable == True:
                if self.destructCountDown == self.countdown:
                    self.destruct()
            if self.destructCountDown <= 0:
                return False
            else:
                if self.explodable == True:
                    if self.exploded == False:
                        if self.arc == True:
                            print self.destructCountDown, (self.full-self.countdown)/2
                            if self.destructCountDown > (self.full-self.countdown)/2:
                                self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                                self.directions[0], self.directions[1] = self.adjustmag(self.directions[0], self.directions[1],-1)
                            else:
                                self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                                self.directions[0], self.directions[1] = self.adjustmag(self.directions[0], self.directions[1],1)
                        else:
                            self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                else:
                    if self.arc == True:
                        if self.destructCountDown > self.full/2:
                            self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                            self.directions[0], self.directions[1] = self.adjustmag(self.directions[0], self.directions[1],-1)
                        else:
                            self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                            self.directions[0], self.directions[1] = self.adjustmag(self.directions[0], self.directions[1],1)
                    else:
                        self.rect.move_ip(*self.directions)
                return True
    def adjustmag(self,x,y,change):
        angle = math.atan2(y,x)
        print "x, y: ", x, y
        magnitude = math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)
        print "magnitude: ", magnitude
        if magnitude > 1 and change < 0:
            magnitude = float(magnitude) + float(change)
        elif change > 0:
            magnitude = float(magnitude) + float(change)
        nx = math.cos(angle)*float(magnitude)
        ny = math.sin(angle)*float(magnitude)
        return nx, ny
    def end(self):
        drawn.remove(self)
        collidable.remove(self)
        updated.remove(self)
        damagers.remove(self)
        explosion_triggers.remove(self)
```

This code is part of a larger program and won't work if you run it, it also includes a number of features you shouldn't need, but this is a good, well implemented example of how projectiles should be structured. The basic idea, however, is that the unit manages the updating of the projectiles and has a function to fire them, the projectiles have internal update functions to move, manage their own image upon initializing as sprites (they are there own class), and manage their own annihilation inside the update function, which they can return to the player, and the game draws everything.